# How to filter values returned on a filed defined as foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

In models.py I have two models:

```
class X(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Y(models.Model):
    id_fk = models.ForeignKey(X,related_name='x_y')
```

in views.py:

```
class CreateY(generic.CreateView):
    model = Y
```

---

now the field `Y.id_fk` will be a list of values of all in `X.id`

the question is:
how can i add extra condition?

means if `X.id = 1,2,3,4,5`
then available values for `Y.id_fk` will be the same 
but what if i want to display only values `<= 3`

how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Add `form` class and html template to help understand the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps queryset lookups could be helpful using the underscore notation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#lt is an example of retrieving field data less than some value.